# Strange trigonometric equation: $2\sin x+x\cos x=0$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I have to solve the following trigonometric equation:
$$2\sin(x)+x\cos(x)=0.$$

This problem comes from an analytical geometry one. I have tried to find the exact solutions, but I didn't succeed. Is there any method to find them? If not, how to approximate the solutions? I have no experience to approximate solutions of such equations, so any general approach would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: I need to find all the solutions :)

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding solutions to $x = - \tan x$. Draw the graphs of $y=x$ and $y= -2 \tan x$ and you can clearly see that they intersect only at $x=0$

Comment: @SandeepThilakan you likely mean $x = -2\tan x$...

Comment: @SandeepThilakan There are infinite many solutions. (of course only one solation in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 3):

Since no zero of $\cos(x)$ would solve the equation (as this would require $\sin(x)$ to be zero as well), we can exclude these points and reformulate or equation to $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\frac{x}{2}.$$

Since the tangens is a strictly increasing function, and $-x/2$ is strictly decreasing, there is at most one solution in every interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi), \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since the range of the tangens is $\mathbb{R}$ in each of the intervals, there is exactly one solution of this equation in each of the intervals. For $k=0$, this is $x=0$.

One way to find these points would be graphical and to plot the functions $\tan$ and $-x/2$.

Another (numerical) option is to use [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for the function $\tan(x)+x/2$, starting in the interval you are interested in.